# How to control source ip or port for UDP packet with nodejs

Tags: node.js, udp, ip, integration-testing, snmp

I'm working on an application that interfaces with embedded equipment via the SNMP protocol. To facilitate testing, I've written a simulator for the embedded equipment with Nodejs and the [snmpjs library](http://joyent.github.io/node-snmpjs/). The simulator responds to SNMP gets/sets and sends traps to the managing application. The trap messages are constructed by the snmpjs library, but sent manually using Node's standard UDP sockets.

This works well when simulating one equipment, but I've run into an issue when attempting to simulate multiple equipment. Specifically, the managing application identifies the source equipment of SNMP traps by analyzing the source IP/port of the UDP packet carrying the trap. This precludes my simulating multiple equipment simultaneously, which is the most common use case for the application.

So, my question is: Is there some way to control/spoof the source IP or port of the udp packet with Nodejs? Or, perhaps, would it be possible to use some kind of proxy to achieve the desired result?

(Note: Running the simulators on a single machine is a strict requirement. Also, it is not sufficient that I have unique IPs/ports for each simulator, I must be able to know their values ahead of time so that I can configure the managing application to interface with them correctly.)

Comment: Oops... The solution was simple. I overlooked this line from the node documentation for the `send` method of udp sockets, "If the socket has not been previously bound with a call to bind, it's assigned a random port number..." I just needed to bind the socket to a port first. I've verified this with a test script.

Comment: I think it's alright to answer your own question in this case. Isn't it?

Comment: I believe you're right. I was unable to until 24 hours had past originally, so I posted the comment. I've pasted the comment as an answer for clarity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was simple. I overlooked this line from the node documentation for the `send` method of udp sockets, "If the socket has not been previously bound with a call to bind, it's assigned a random port number..." I just needed to bind the socket to a port first. I've verified this with a test script.

Comment: But that doesn'twork for IP spoofing, at least on windows I get `EADDRNOTAVAIL` error.